# Take Full page screenshots in Chrome without stitching image

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, screenshot

I was looking at options to take full page screenshots in Chrome using selenium. It seems that the default screenshot options takes only the visible section of the view port size of the browser.

I tried implementing a workaround I read on the internet where I can take multiple screenshot by scrolling using Javascript and then stitch the images to make it a complete page screenshot. However, there were cases in which the final image has a lot of overlaps and disconnect from the original page.

I also read that following code can take full screen screenshots using Chrome but there was no success:

```
public class chrome_test_service {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriverService.Builder builder =  new ChromeDriverService.Builder();
    ChromeDriverService srvc = builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File(".\chromedriver.exe")).build();
    try {
        srvc.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(srvc);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Chrome Driver");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Object width=js.executeScript("return Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth);");
    Object height=js.executeScript("return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);");
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(Integer.parseInt(width.toString()), Integer.parseInt(height.toString()));
    driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    synchronized (scrFile) 
    {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("abc.jpg"));   
    }
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

any suggestions to get full page screenshots like Firefox using Chrome?